# How to count elements using a stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I need to load file data in arraylist which I have done by creating a method. How can I count number of students using streams by creating a separate method for counting. I have a student class with constructor, getters and setters.

I have a file having data as

> Name: a
>
> Subjects : eng, phy, chem
>
> Name: b
>
> Subjects : math, bio
>
> //name is variable in student class // getName is the getter

```
List<Student> stu = new ArrayList<>():


public static Map<String,Long> names(List<Student> name, Predicate <Student> getName) {      
    Map<String, Long> n  = stu.stream()
    .filter(getName)    
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getName(),Collectors.counting()));
    System.out.println(Collectors.counting());
    return n;
}
```

It should just display the number of students.

Comment: Not really clear, what is it that you're trying to count? If you wish to display the total number of students, why no use `stu.size()`? Another point, if `getName` filters a specific name, `groupingBy` using name doesn't really make sense when you just wanted to `count`.

Comment: number of students using streams. I dont have to take into account the subjects .

Comment: Just use `stu.size()` to *count the number of students.* ... Another - `System.out.println(Collectors.counting());` wouldn't really be helpful either.

Comment: So for the sample data in your question the count would be 2? Because there is data for 2 students.

Comment: or do you want to count the students that fulfill a given predicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you insist on using a stream (which certainly isn’t recommended for the number of elements in a list):

```
public static int count(List<Student> listOfStudents) {
    long count = listOfStudents.stream().count();
    int n = Math.toIntExact(count);
    return n;
}
```

Since `Stream.count()` returns a `long` either your method must return a `long`, which I found pointless since we know that the a list cannot hold a higher number of students than can fit into an `int`; or we need to convert from `long` to `int`. I am using `Math.toIntExact` for the conversion.

The comments are correct: it would be easier and recommended to use `listOfStudents.size()` (and no stream).

What your method in the question seemed to be doing was count the students having the same name. In your example the result might be `{a=1,b=1}`. But only if both students satisfied the predicate also passed to the method.

A tip: take care to use telling names in your program, it means a whole lot to readability. Call you method for example `count` or `getNumberOfStudents`(not `names`). Call the parameter holding the list for example `students` or `studentList` (not `name`). Don’t call your predicate the same as the getter (a predicate and a getter are two very different things). Also `n` for the return value doesn’t really tell anything and leaves us wondering what you want the method to return. It’s not just for our sake (though pleasing other Stackers is a good and cheap way to get good answers); I think that good names will also help yourself keep your thoughts about the program clearer.